# How can I modify this code in such a way multiple corresponding characters are printed out once in occurance

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, loops

`p` occurred twice in the output because of the word `apples`.

I am trying to modify the code in such a way `p` is printed once in the output. Thanks

```py
def in_both(word1, word2):
    for letter in word1:
        if letter not in word2:
            print (letter)

print(in_both("apples", "oranges"))
```

current **output:**

```
p
p
l
none
```

expected **output:**

```
p
l
none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store letters already seen in a data structure. In this case a `set()` is most appropriate since you can have `O(1)` lookup and addition

```
def in_both(word1, word2):
    known_letters = set()
    for letter in word1:
        if letter not in word2 and letter not in known_letters:
            print(letter)
            known_letters.add(letter)

print(in_both("apples", "oranges"))
```

Also your code will print a final `None` since it's the return value of `in_both`, so I would suggest removing the `print` call arround `in_both("apples", "oranges")`